# Are long high volume transactions bad

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

Hallo,

I am writing a database application that does a lot of inserts and updates with fake `serialisable` isolation level (`snapshot isolation`).

To not do tonnes of network roundtrips I'm batching inserts and updates in one transaction with `PreparedStatement`s. They should fail very seldom because the inserts are prechecked and nearly conflict free to other transactions, so rollbacks don't occur often.

Having big transactions should be good for WAL, because it can flush big chunks and doesn't have to flush for mini transactions.

1.) I can only see positive effects of a big transaction. But I often read that they are bad. Why could they be bad in my use case?

2.) Is the checking for conflicts so expensive when the `local snapshots` are merged back into the real database? The database will have to compare all write sets of possible conflicts (parallel transaction). Or does it do some high speed shortcut? Or is that quite cheap anyways?

[**EDIT**] It might be interesting if someone could bring some clarity into how a snapshot isolation database checks if transaction, which have overlapping parts on the timeline, are checked for disjunct write sets. Because that's what fake serializable isolation level is all about.

Comment: why do you want to change the isolation level exactly?  I do a fair amount of batch work and never touch default isolation levels

Comment: because I don't want to have lost updates. And they can happen with any other lower isolation level.

Comment: You can work with the default serialization level (READ COMMITED) **and** prevent lost updates, you just need to implement an approrpriate locking mechanism, either [optimistic locking or pessimistic locking](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:68123251882436)

Comment: You could also use advisory locks in your app. They're extremely powerful for this kind of stuff, and you'd be able to not interfere with misc tables that don't need the same level of isolation.

Comment: I would really like to say with the high isolation level, because I can't take any risk. The question was any way more about how long transaction affect this isolation level.

Comment: Suggest you open different questions for ORACLE and POSTGRES as the underlying architectures are very different and what is a good strategy for one might be poor in another. Broadly, oracle is quite happy with long running, large transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issues here are two fold.  The first possible problem is bloat.  Large transactions can result in a lot of dead tuples showing up at once.  The other possible problem is from long running transactions.  As long as a long running transaction is running, the tables it's touching can't be vacuumed so can collect lots of dead tuples as well.

I'd say just use check_postgresql.pl to check for bloating issues.  As long as you don't see a lot of table bloat after your long transactions you're ok.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good idea. The transation are not so massiv, always far below 0.1% of the total data. If I go for oracle, I think (guess) they anyways use in place updates and do rollbacks and version control with the WAL. Therefor not needing GC. But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

1) Manual says that it is good: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html

I can recommend also to Use COPY, Remove Indexes (but first test), Increase maintenance_work_mem, Increase checkpoint_segments, Run ANALYZE (or VACUUM ANALYZE) Afterwards.

I will not recommed if you are not sure: Remove Foreign Key Constraints, Disable WAL archival and streaming replication.

2) Always data are merged on commit but there is no checks, data are just written. Read again: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html

If your inserts/updates does not depend on other inserts/updates you don't need "wholly consistent view". You may use read committed and transaction will never fail.

Comment: The populate doc is great, but I think that's really targeted at loading data into an **offline** database.  For example, temporarily removing indexes on a table will acquire an exclusive lock on that table, blocking all other transactions.  Sounds like the OP is loading data into an active system.

Comment: yes you're right there, it's a active system. The application layer should provide protection against logical conflicts, but I would like the databse to be the master of correct information (if it doesn't cost too much). On your second link I'm missing the information how the local snapshots are merged, where is that written? I do think the database has to check if the write sets of partially parallel transactions are disjuct, if the're not disjunct the exception is thrown. That's the checking I'm talking about.

Comment: Snapshots are not merged. There is locks before updates if other transaction want to update same row.